# Jquery $.fn not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

fn to create functions/methods before without any hassle, however, I'm now having some issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
$.fn.formClass = function(class) 
{

var bad_class = (class=='input_good') ? 'input_bad' : 'input_good';
if($(this).hasClass(bad_class))$(this).removeClass(bad_class);
 $(this).addClass(class);

}
```

and I'm trying to use it inside this function:

```
function check_username()
{

var username = $('input[name="username"]');
if(username.val().length<4||username.val.length>20)
{username.formClass('input_bad');}
}
```

The Console.log is saying Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'formClass'

Thanks is advance for any help!

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword it cannot be the name of a function parameter. Is it named differently in your code?

Comment: Is the top block definitely being called before the bottom one? (assuming it's named something differently in your code and thus actually *working*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you should be getting an error about using the variable name `class` since it is a reserved keyword. Try renaming it to something else:

```
$.fn.formClass = function(class_name) {
  var bad_class = (class_name=='input_good') ? 'input_bad' : 'input_good';
  if($(this).hasClass(bad_class))$(this).removeClass(bad_class);
  $(this).addClass(class_name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, TheZ. It works perfectly! I will mark as answered when it allows me. :)

Comment: @RossWilson No problem, I had the console open and got the `SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word` error. `class` sounded like the most obvious candidate so a simple `var class = "test"` throwing the error was all I needed to confirm :)